# communciation with Fluke endurance pyrometer (profinet/RS485) via python

Tags: python, ping, ethernet, rs485, snap7

I have a Fluke Endurance pyrometer (and a pretty flimsy user guide) which has output via an ethernet cable which I'm then connecting to my computer via a USB3.0 to Gigabit ethernet adaptor (windows control panel tells me it's working).  According to the guide, communication should be possible via RS485 and profinet.  But it's unclear to me if both are possible through the same cable.

My initial plan was to try to use snap7 to try profinet communication, but when I try:

```
import snap7
plc = snap7.client.Client()
plc.connect("192.168.42.132",0,1)
```

I get

```
snap7.snap7exceptions.Snap7Exception: b' TCP : Unreachable peer'
```

I can ping the device at that IP address.

So my questions are:

1. any ideas why I can ping, but snap7 seems to have problems connecting?
2. if I can't get profinet communication to work, any chance I can get RS485 communication somehow through the ethernet cable?  Everything I looked up on that talks about having hardware that does the conversion, so I'm assuming it's more than just looking for the right signal format on the right wires.  I can't find anything in the manual that turns on/off one form of communication, and it looks like from the menu they are both active, if that's possible.

Better yet, if anyone has communicated with this device in python, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Matthew

Update:

In case anyone else has a similar problem, I solved this by using socket and ASCII commands like this:

```
import socket 
pyrometerIP = "192.168.42.132"
pyrometerPORT = 6363

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.settimeout(3) # 3 second timeout on commands
s.connect((pyrometerIP, pyrometerPORT))


MESSAGE=bytes('U=C\r', 'ascii')
s.send(MESSAGE)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of reasons why, some of the reason are listed below:

1. The rack and slot available to over TIA portal.
2. You cannot reach the PLC on that IP
3. You do not have the two DLL file for snap7 module which can be found on https://sourceforge.net/projects/snap7/files/1.4.2/